# Execução em multiprocessadores

Tags: python, multithreading

Estou pesquisando sobre execução paralela em Python e fiquei com uma dúvida que ainda não achei resposta clara.

Digamos que eu queira multiplicar duas matrizes e adiciona em uma lista de tarefas onde cada tarefa é uma linha da matriz A e uma coluna da matriz B e peça que `n` *threads* retire desta lista uma tarefa para multiplicar.

Eu tenho 4 *cores* na máquina, utilizando o módulo `threading.Thread` do Python, se eu criar 4 *theads* para execução da lista de tarefas, essas *threads* serão executadas uma em cada *core*? Ou seja, paralelamente? Ou para isso eu precisaria utilizar o módulo `multiprocessing` que divide as tarefas em 1 processo para cada *core*?

Se somente com `multiprocessing` eu consigo distribuir as tarefas nos 4 *cores*, como faço para, por exemplo, definir 2 *threads* em cada processo ou seja cada *core* receberia 2 *threads* para processamento da minha tarefa?

Comment: Algo que já recomendo você pesquisar é sobre o GIL (*Global Interpreter Lock*), no Python, que resumidamente fala que o interpretador só pode ser utilizado por apenas uma *thread* por vez.

Comment: Você tentou algo? Adicione a sua pergunta o que você já tentou

Comment: Ainda não desenvolvi estou tentando entender como usar os 4 processadores da máquina com python, não sei se pelo fato de criar 4 threads automaticamente cada uma será executada em cada processador.

Comment: Na verdade, em Python puro, apenas uma thread é executada por vez, não importa quantos nucleos você tenha. Numpy já não é Python puro - e na verdade, ele já paraleliza esse tipo de operação em vários núcleos sozinho. Pra fins didáticos sim, tem bastante coisa pra falar aí.

Tenho algumas respostas já sobre multiprocessamento com Python - vou dar uma olhada se alguma é equivalente a essa sua

Comment: ssas duas respostas tem bastante detalhe do que você precisa entender agora - tanto de como Python trabalha com multi-threading e multi-processing, como como fazer. 

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146417/fibonacci-com-execu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-paralelo-threads/146458#146458 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197174/python-c%c3%b3digo-serial-vs-multiprocessing-vs-threading/197678#197678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [*thread*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101) existe para permitir o processamento concorrente. Não há garantias que a execução será feita em processadores diferentes. É garantido que se tiver apenas a *thread* principal só executará em um processador. Dito isto, é provável que utilize todos os processadores disponíveis se tiver pelo menos uma *thread* para cada um deles. Neste caso rodará tudo em paralelo.

Na verdade essa é a melhor forma de se criar uma *thread*. Não gosto do seu uso quando na verdade só deseja assincronia de execução.

De forma geral você não tem controle onde será executado, no máximo pode estabelecer afinidade e prioridade, mas não sei se tem API que lide com isto. [Tem para o processo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

Não sei mexer com *threads* em Python. Me lembro que tinha algum problema com o [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), mas não entendo todas as consequências disso para dar mais detalhes.

Algumas pessoas preferem fazer isso em outro nível, em C por exemplo. Deve ter um motivo.

Se vai conseguir paralelizar de forma adequada é outra questão.

Veja isto para te ajudar tomar uma decisão: [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101)

Comment: Bacana esse que me indicou. Mas ainda não sei se criar 4 threads em python vai fazer com que cada um dos 4 processadores receberão uma thread para executar

Comment: Não - a VM do Python executa bytecode em apenas um núcleo por vez - o tal "Global Interpreter Lock" - só quando a execução chama uma função em código nativo, que libera o GIL, mais de um núcleo pode ser usado. Em Python, threads são apenas uma forma simplíssima de resolver paralelismo quando o problema é latência/espera de eventos de I/O. O Numpy no entanto já usa mais de um núcleo em suas computações sem precisar fazer mais nada.